# Consensus sequence from SAM or BAM file?

Tags: sam, genome, assembly

I am trying to perform reference-based assembly. Most of the tutorials teach how to create a bam file and view alignemnts in IGV or Tablet. But, I want a assembled genome sequence in fasta format. How can I do that ? Is there any tool or linux syntax available for this purpose ?

Comment: Cross-posted on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/374352/

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I used AlignGraph ([paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4058956/) and [code](https://github.com/baoe/AlignGraph)) for a task like this. I gave AlignGraph my raw reads, so I'm not sure if it accepts SAM/BAM input or if you have to go back to the original Fastq reads.

I'm not sure if any related/improved tools have been published since AlignGraph. Internet searches for "reference-guided assembly" return mostly transcriptome assembly tools. It might be worth looking for [articles that cite the AlignGraph paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?linkname=pubmed_pubmed_citedin&from_uid=24932000).

Comment: It seems like AlignGraph takes reads in fasta format. Does it accept fastq format ? What tool do you use to convert fastq to fasta format ?

Comment: `cat reads.fastq | paste - - - - | cut -f 1-2 | sed 's/^@/>/' | tr '\t' '\n' > reads.fasta`. You can replace `cat` with `gunzip -c` if your Fastqs are compressed.